# What is Parity doing after warp sync besides importing new blocks?

Tags: parity, parity-wallet

I noticed Parity is still busy working on old blocks after a warp sync - but it doesn't really tell why. e.g.

```
2018-06-07 08:38:14 UTC Imported #5746763 098a…98f4 (37 txs, 1.69 Mgas, 137.63 ms, 8.11 KiB)
2018-06-07 08:38:34 UTC Syncing #5746763 098a…98f4     0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s      0+    0 Qed  #5746764    6/100 peers      5 MiB chain  117 MiB db  0 bytes queue   10 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn, 22 req/s, 115 µs
2018-06-07 08:39:05 UTC Syncing #5746764 e094…7fb0     0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s      0+    0 Qed  #5746760   11/100 peers    315 KiB chain  117 MiB db  0 bytes queue    6 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn, 57 req/s,  91 µs
2018-06-07 08:39:05 UTC Syncing #5746764 e094…7fb0     0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s      0+    0 Qed  #5746760   11/100 peers      2 MiB chain  117 MiB db  0 bytes queue    6 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn, 57 req/s,  91 µs
2018-06-07 08:39:47 UTC   #5101162    1/100 peers     40 KiB chain  117 MiB db  0 bytes queue    8 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn, 10 req/s,  43 µs
2018-06-07 08:39:47 UTC   #5101162    1/100 peers     53 KiB chain  117 MiB db  0 bytes queue    8 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn, 11 req/s,  98 µs
2018-06-07 08:39:47 UTC   #5101162    1/100 peers     53 KiB chain  117 MiB db  0 bytes queue    8 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn, 18 req/s, 631 µs
2018-06-07 08:39:47 UTC   #5101162    1/100 peers     53 KiB chain  117 MiB db  0 bytes queue    8 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn, 18 req/s, 631 µs
2018-06-07 08:40:32 UTC Imported #5746771 564f…171e (139 txs, 7.99 Mgas, 851.06 ms, 27.05 KiB) + another 1 block(s) containing 241 tx(s)
2018-06-07 08:40:32 UTC   #5101480    1/100 peers      5 MiB chain  118 MiB db  0 bytes queue   15 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn, 11 req/s, 8792769 µs
2018-06-07 08:40:32 UTC   #5101480    1/100 peers      5 MiB chain  118 MiB db  0 bytes queue   15 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn, 11 req/s, 8792769 µs
2018-06-07 08:40:32 UTC   #5101480    1/100 peers      5 MiB chain  118 MiB db  0 bytes queue   15 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn, 10 req/s, 1569665 µs
2018-06-07 08:40:32 UTC   #5101480    1/100 peers      5 MiB chain  118 MiB db  0 bytes queue   15 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn, 10 req/s, 1569665 µs
```

The first few lines are understandable - #5746763 and #5746764 are new blocks from the network. But afterwards it's still doing something with #5101480 - and apparently, that took >8.7s, which caused the Parity node to be temporarily unresponsive to RPC calls.

What's happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do a warp sync, it gets a snapshot of the current state of all accounts. But how does that's the right snapshot? It doesn't. It assumes it is, for now, but goes back and downloads all the blocks leading up to this snapshot, and validates them (or at least, validates their proof of work). That's what the old blocks are for.